# Nested bulleted lists in roff/groff?

Tags: groff

I'm trying to construct a nested bulleted list in roff. I'm on macOS, using GNU groff version 1.19.2.

From the roff documentation, it seems like the `.IP` macro is an appropriate way to do this. So I'm `.IP` for the bulleted items, in combination with `.RS`/`.RE` to indent the margin for the nested lists.

```
.SH "Nested three deep"
.IP \(bu 1
foo
.IP \(bu 1
bar
.RS
.IP \(bu 2
foo\-2
.IP \(bu 2
bar\-2
.RS
.IP \(bu 3
foo\-3
.IP \(bu 3
bar\-3
.RE
.IP \(bu 2
baz\-2
.RS
.IP \(bu 3
foo\-3
.RE
.IP \(bu 2
qux\-2
.RE
.IP \(bu 1
baz
```

But the bullet/text alignment on the first level of the list is incorrect: the text appears on the line below the bullet, not immediately after the bullet.

[image: mis-formatted roff nested list]

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Increase 1 to 2. `.IP \[bu] 2`. Use this same value thruout. Do not use 1 or 3. That does not do what you seem to think it does.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by the first comment, you have a misconception regarding the 2nd argument (the number) to the `.IP` macro: it only adjusts the indent of the body text with respect to the bullet point.

The nested indentation is done with the `.RS`/`.RE` macros (RS=right shift).